# Is it possible to join TempView in spark, as it is throwing cannot resolve symbol error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to join 3 view in Apache Spark with scala

```
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("customer")
finaldf.createOrReplaceTempView("product")
areadf.createOrReplaceTempView("sales")
```

**Libraries:**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SaveMode, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

Joining view below

```
val result = customer.join(product, customer("keycol")===product("keycol"))
```

but not sure why it is not recognize registered view
Any miss.... Please suggest

Do i need to import any specific library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to import any library, Once we **`create temp view`** then we need to use **`SQL api`** to join syntax the temp views.

**`Example:`**

```
spark.sql("select * from customer c join product p on c.keycol=p.keycol")

//join using dataframe api
df1.join(finaldf, df1("keycol")===finaldf("keycol"))
```